# Downloading file through Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have files in zip format which I want to  download through Yii's sendFile() method. But it gives me an error `File not found`. But when check with `file_exist()` - it returns true. Following is the code to download the file.

```
Yii::app()->request->sendFile($product->zfile, $file_url, "zip", FALSE);
```

**USING:**
Windows, 
XAMPP, 
Yii (**v1.1.16**)

Comment: What does your `file_exists()` code look like?

Comment: file_exists(YiiBase::getPathOfAlias("webroot") . "/themefiles/" . $product->zfile)

Comment: That method does not accept file path, only file content ( [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#sendFile-detail) ). Additionally mime type should be `application/zip` not just zip. Also I suppose that `File not found` error is not caused by this, rather you have problem with routing or rewriting and you're not hitting correct controller with your request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing the proper arguments.

Pass file content instead of `$file_url`.

Pass mimeType as `'application/zip'` instead of `'zip'`.

```
Yii::app()->request->sendFile($outputFileName, $content, $mimeType, $terminate);

Yii::app()->request->sendFile("Test.zip", @file_get_contents($path), 'application/zip', false);
```

[Yii sendFile method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#sendFile-detail)